# Java abstract class for dynamic JDBC requests

Tags: java, jdbc, abstract-class

I am currently reworking an ADF Fusion application, that uses a lot of Java nested in Beans to actually manage JDBC requests. As the code ermerged from the pre-Java8 era there is a bunch of deprecated technologies in it and I neither have the time nor the knowledge to rework everything (which describes the percentage of the code that is outdated and hard to debug).

Something very regularly is that inside the backing bean classes manual JDBC requests with our inhouse DB are handled (often uncannily nested in other methods). As I began to outsource them I realized I wrote the same block of code over and over again:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    conn = CC.getConn(); //CC is of type "CustomConnection", 
                         //a static assist class that fetches the connection
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("Some SQL");
    while(rs.next()) {
        //handle the result
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

or for `PreparedStatement` respectively:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    conn = CC.getConn(); //CC is of type "CustomConnection", 
                         //a static assist class that fetches the connection
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("Some SQL");
    //populate the pstmt with params 
    rs = pstmt.executeUpdate();
    while(rs.next()) {
        //handle the result
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While I'm aware that this is not the best practice it worked reliable so far but writing multiple methods like this with real difference only in the handling of the `ResultSet` became very tedious. So my approach was to write an abstract superclass that provides a `request()` method and let the extending classes define the parameters to populate a `PreparedStatement` and the handling of the `ResultSet`.

```
public abstract class Requestable {
    
    public void request(String SQL, HashMap<String, Integer> args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        
        try {
            conn = CC.getConn();
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            pstmt = fill(args);
            onResponse(pstmt.executeUpdate());
            //handle result
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract PreparedStatement fill(HashMap args);

    public abstract void onResponse(ResultSet rs);

    public Requestable() {
        super();
    }
}
```

This would be an example for `PreparedStatement`. `Statement`s would get an own separate method.

Writing this draft, I came across the issue that some classes which are intended to extend `Requestable` currently have multiple different requests that they perform (which all need a specific handling of the result). With my approach, I could define the methods `fill()` and  `onResponse()` only once per class. Is there a way to like pass a function reference to `request()` that gets defined in the extending class and executed at the position of `fill()` and `onResponse()`?

Comment: The IDE used is JDeveloper v12.2.1.4.0, Java8 and Oracle 12c Database

Comment: You can make the error handling much simpler with try-with-resources.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen did you mean auto-closable ressources? Yeah I've read about that, and as soon as I have modularized the request processing i'm definitely trying that out. Not too familiar with it yet.

Comment: Have a look at it, it will make your life easier.  Please note that your current exception handling will most likely give you problems as the calling code has no idea if anything went wrong.